# What are the attributes of the false teachers in 2 Peter 2?

Tags: sin, judgement

What is the status of who these false teachers were. Were they once saved and fell away. What was the primary reason for them to be judged?

Comment: Welcome to the site DH. Good question. For future reference it's helpful to include the actual quote in addition to chapter and verse (this is not required but it does save readers some trouble). and it lets us know the translation you are using.

Answer (score 6):

In 2 Peter 2, the false teachers are described as having **several attributes:**

1. **Destructive Heresies.** They introduced destructive heresies, denying the Lord who bought them, bringing swift destruction upon themselves (2 Peter 2:1).
2. **Deceptive Practices.** They exploited their followers with deceptive words (2 Peter 2:3).
3. **Immorality.** They indulged in sensuality, enticing unstable souls (2 Peter 2:14).
4. **Greed/Covetousness.**  They were motivated by greed, exploiting their followers. They have a heart trained in covetous practices. (2 Peter 2:3, 14-15).
5. **Arrogance.** They were arrogant and self-willed, not afraid to speak evil of glorious ones (2 Peter 2:10-11).

**Were they once saved and fell away?**

The text doesn't explicitly state whether they were once saved and fell away. However, the phrase "denying the Lord who bought them" (2 Peter 2:1) suggests that they were associated with the Christian community in some way but turned away from the true faith. This could imply that they had knowledge, or at least some knowledge of salvation but ultimately rejected it.

**What was the primary reason for them to be judged?**

The primary reason for their judgment seems to be their promotion of false teachings and their sinful behavior, which led others astray and brought dishonor to the name of Christ. They exploited and misled vulnerable believers for their own gain, demonstrating a blatant disregard for the truth and the consequences of their actions. Therefore, they faced severe judgment for their ungodly deeds and teachings.

Comment: +1. Good answer.

Comment: + 1 But I think it is possible to identify a specific heresy 2 Pt is most concerned with, namely the denial of the Second Coming.

Answer (score 1):

2 Pt. 2:1-2

> There will be false teachers among you, who will introduce destructive heresies and even deny the Master who ransomed them, bringing swift destruction on themselves. 2 Many will follow their licentious ways, and because of them the way of truth will be reviled.

Note that this is phrased in the future tense: not "there are" but there "shall be" false teachers among you. So the author seems to be prophesying about a future situation. This does not rule out that the issues were already present in the church. As to which heresies and practices he refers to, I agree with @Jason's answer. But the OP asks which one is primary. To me it is clear that 2 Peter is most concerned with the denial of Christ's coming. This issue was already present in the church, and would naturally become more intense as expectations of Christ's immediate return waned. Moreover, the letter instructs its readers to be aware of this issue "first of all."

2 Peter 3

> 3 Know this first of all, that in the last days scoffers will come
> scoff, living according to their own desires 4 and saying, “Where is
> the promise of his coming? From the time when our ancestors fell
> asleep, everything has remained as it was from the beginning of
> creation.” 5 They deliberately ignore the fact that the heavens
> existed of old and earth was formed out of water and through water by
> the word of God; 6 through these the world that then existed was
> destroyed, deluged with water. 7 The present heavens and earth have
> been reserved by the same word for fire, kept for the day of judgment
> and of destruction of the godless. 8 But do not ignore this one fact,
> beloved, that with the Lord one day is like a thousand years and a
> thousand years like one day. 9 The Lord does not delay his promise, as
> some regard “delay,” but he is patient with you, not wishing that any
> should perish but that all should come to repentance. 10 But the day
> of the Lord will come like a thief, and then the heavens will pass
> away with a mighty roar and the elements will be dissolved by fire,
> and the earth and everything done on it will be found out.

**Conclusion**: Based on the phrase "know this first of all" and the amount of space he devotes to this topic in a short letter, the primary heresy dealt with in 2 Peter is the denial of the promise of the Second Coming and final judgment. These teachers once accepted Christ, but lost faith (or will lose it) because they expected Jesus to return very soon and were disappointed when he did not do so. The "licentious ways" referred to in 2:2 are the fruit of a heretical seed: since Christ is not coming, one need not be concerned about being judged so "anything goes."

Comment: +1. A valid perspective on the primary heresy.